# Why am I able to use the pygame module methods in one .py file even though I imported the module in another file?

Tags: python, python-import

I have two .py files. One of them is the main file with all the code and the other one is the file I decided to create to clean up my main file. I wanted to create a separate class in order to get the main file more organised, then simply import the class in the main file.

I was expecting that I'd have to import pygame in the additional file as well in order to use the methods it'd provide, such as `.blit` or `.render`. However, I noticed that PyCharm suggested me to get rid of the import, as it was redundant and never used. [This is how the code in the additional file looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpcVY.png). It uses the dis variable (`dis = pygame.display.set_mode((DIS_WIDTH, DIS_HEIGHT))` ) that I'm passing in the main.py.

My own guess is that maybe the fact that I'm passing the dis variable accounts for this, but I'm not sure how it's done, since I'm new to OOP and to programming in general. I tried to look for the answer on the web, but I didn't find anything that would remind me my problem. So, I really hope there is an explanation for this kind of behavior.

```
from constants import * #constants is another additional file, containing some variables


class Scoreboard:
    def __init__(self, m_display):
        self.display = m_display
        self.width = DIS_WIDTH
        self.height = DIS_HEIGHT

    def message(self, msg, color):
        mesg = MAIN_FONT_STYLE.render(msg, True, color)
        self.display.blit(mesg, [self.width / 6, self.height / 3])

    def your_score(self, score):
        value = SCORE_FONT_STYLE.render("Your Score: " + str(score), True, YELLOW)
        self.display.blit(value, [0, 0])
```

`constants.py` contains `import pygame` in itself.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
MAIN_FONT_STYLE = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 25)
SCORE_FONT_STYLE = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 35)
```

Comment: You should post some code in the question.  In the meantime I'm guessing you used `from my_module import *`.

Comment: Is `MAIN_FONT_STYLE` in `constants.py`? Your .py gets the object in `MAIN_FONT_STYLE` from its module namespace (presumably from the import) but then the `.render` comes from `MAIN_FONT_STYLE's namespace, not your imported namespace.

Comment: Mark Ransom, thank you for the response! If you mean that I used ```from my_module import *``` in the main file, then you're correct. That's what I did.

Comment: tdelaney, thank you for the response! Yes, ```MAIN_FONT_STYLE``` is indeed in ```constants.py```. In ```constants.py``` I have ```import pygame```.

Comment: `.blit` and `.render` are methods of an object. You do not need to import the module that implements the class if you import the instance object itself. By the way, this question has nothing to do with pygame and this is nothing special about pygame. This is just a python behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `from constants import *` you import *everything* that is defined in the module `constants`, including anything it has imported itself.  That can be a lot more than you bargained for, and can cause conflicts by defining names that you didn't expect.  That's why it's not recommended practice.  Instead, you can just qualify each symbol with the module name:

```
import constants
# ...
mesg = constants.MAIN_FONT_STYLE.render(msg, True, color)
```

Or you can import only the things that you need:

```
from constants import MAIN_FONT_STYLE, SCORE_FONT_STYLE
```

P.S. the suggestion is correct, you don't need to import the module to use the methods on the objects it creates.